# Visual Studio 2017 For Mac doesn't show all Nunit Tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nunit, xunit, visual-studio-mac

So Visual Studio doesn't seem to register all my Unit Tests. I have no idea how to solve this, and google hasn't been able to help.

Most of the tests is for some reason labeled as "Inconclusive Tests". This is how the built in Unit Tests displays:

[image]

P.S. The test runner works fine when I run the tests in a terminal.

Comment: No, I'm not. You can check out the code here https://github.com/jesperlandmer/Snake-Game

Comment: If this is a .NET Core project then this is due to a bug in Visual Studio for Mac 7.2. This bug should be fixed in Visual Studio for Mac 7.3, which is available on the alpha channel.

Comment: Works in Version 7.3 Preview (7.3 build 764)

Comment: @MattWard Yes, thank you! It now works! Write it as an answer, and I'll check it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core test projects in Visual Studio for Mac 7.2 has a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/90031/test-pad-breaks-after-exceeding-9-test-methods-xun.html) that would cause the test names to appear blank in the Unit Tests window. This problem was fixed in Visual Studio for Mac 7.3.